# How do I carry a Joomla article title and its link across from an article layout into a module's helper?

Tags: module, articles, joomla-3.9, variable

I have a module that appears on an article page. The module has a form and I would like to send the article's title and page URL as part of the information sent through the form. Using `$this->item->title` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] and read [ask].  Please show us your code that "doesn't work" and please be more descriptive about _how_ it "doesn't work".  Are any errors being generated? White screen of death?  Simply no value is presented where expected?

Comment: Would 2 lines of jQuery be sufficient for this task? or is server side needed for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Factory->getDocument  title and link.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$doc = Factory::getDocument();
$title = $doc->getTitle();
$url = $doc->getLink();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing Fabiano.  Please take our [tour].  If this answer is a little short on specifics for the OP to implement, please be prepared to further explain your recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to carry a variable from page to page php gives us the ability with session. check here: https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/how-tos/development/how-to-use-sessions-in-joomla/

Comment: It is absolutely vital that insights be statically written in the answer.  If the website dies or the page is moved, then the link becomes a deadend and the answer is rendered useless.  It is okay to supply a link to the source that you are referencing, but please copy and quote-format the specific portion of valuable advice here.  If there is too much to sensibly copy into an answer and you'd rather just drop a hyperlink on the page, then the correct action would be to put the link in a comment under the question (once you have the privilege to do so).